# How to check that any error message is diplaying in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

i want to perform an action on onComplete event of commandbutton.I am calling javascript function ,in that function i want to know if there is any error displaying on visualforce page(Validation error).Can i implement this without using any controller.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wonder if you can use the css class `errorMsg` of the error block:

[image]

If this class exists on the page - there is an error:

```
<apex:page>
<script>
function checkIt(){
    if (jQuery('.errorMsg').length > 0){
        // Error exists
        alert('There is an error on the page!');
    }
    else{
        alert('No errors!');
    }
}
</script>

<apex:commandButton reRender="none" oncomplete="checkIt();" value="Click me"/>

</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 7):

Well, you can definitely call ApexPages.hasMessages() from your apex. There's even a version that lets you specify the severity (WARNING, ERROR, FATAL, INFO) that you're looking for.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/apex_System_ApexPages_instance_methods.htm

To use this in your javascript, you could make a controller property or method that returns this result, and then simply access it via mergefield. So for example, you might define a controller method:

```
public Boolean ErrorsPresent(){
    return ApexPages.hasMessages(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR);
}
```

Then your Javascript might looks like

```
if({!ErrorsPresent}){
    alert('Woah there, buddy! Looks like there may be a problem');
}
```

Comment: While that is an interesting solution, the OP specifically asked for something that did not require a controller.

Comment: Ahh, that's actually the exact problem I had been trying to solve when I stumbled across this post, but without the use of Javascript

Answer (score 6):

Pages with a StandardController expose a property:

`{!Messages}`

Without the need for a custom controller or extensions, can do things like:

```
<apex:pageBlock rendered="{!ISNULL(Messages)}">
    <!-- detailed troubleshooting instructions -->
</apex:pageBlock>

<apex:pageBlock rendered="{!NOT(ISNULL(Messages))}">
    <!-- normal page functionality -->
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Answer (score 3):

I found that adding '.empty' to the end was just getting stripped on save, but ISNULL worked fine, as in the following example:

```
rendered="{!ISNULL(messages)}"
```